# Query about an Async operation inside getViews in listView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I was going through this article http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/
to understand the specifics of a task I had at hand .

I had to start a task to download an Image from the internet which I would display at each row .

I do not understand how the following code would work (copied from the article link I posted)

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    ...

    holder.position = position;

    new ThumbnailTask(position, holder)
            .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask {
    private int mPosition;
    private ViewHolder mHolder;

    public ThumbnailTask(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
        mPosition = position;
        mHolder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Download bitmap here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
            mHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView thumbnail;
    public int position;
}
```

Now what I dont understand is that how would the if condition inside onPostExecute work ? . 
mHolder.position=mPosition . Both the values were given to the task when it was being initialized. 
If the views behind are even recycled , how does that affect the mPosition variable inside the AsyncTask ? The task was already launched for example with the mPosition value 2 .

Now when the view is recycled and the position is 15 , how will this be reflected in the task initiated with mPosition  = 2 ?

Please aid .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor of `ThumbnailTask` has 2 parameters; a primitive type position and a reference type holder.

```
   ThumbnailTask(int position, ViewHolder holder)
```

So, position parameter keeps its value same forever(because it is primitive). For example if `ThumbnailTask` is created with 5 for position, then it will be always 5 for that instance. But holder parameter is a reference. If it is being changed somewhere/outside, this is going to effect the value inside the ThumbnailTask.

Here in your list example the most important part for your question is removed ('...' part is shown on the previous example above the page you shared). I get it from the link and combined here. Now it will be more clear to you.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    // '...' parts starts
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.text.setText("Position " + position);
    // '...' parts ends

    holder.position = position;

    return convertView;
}
```

In this part as you see holder instance is not created again if convertView is not null. But its position value is changed. Thus, this change has the same effect on the ThumbnailTask instance which is created before.

Now your question:

> ```
> Now when the view is recycled and the position is 15 , how will this be reflected in the task initiated with mPosition = 2 ?
> ```

Position will keep alwalys same value when it is initiated. But holder is being edited at getView method. So `mHolder.position == mPosition` will be false if holder is used for another list row and downloaded bitmap will be useless.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
        mHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.